# Dot product of HashMap in Groovy

Tags: java, groovy, hashmap, linkedhashmap, dot-product

I have two [LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)s with the same set of keys. I want to perform the dot product between them based on keys.

This is how I am currently doing it:

```
def dotProduct(a,b) {
    acc = 0
    a.keySet().each { acc += a[it] * b[it] }
    acc
}
```

Is there a clearer/faster way?

Comment: You don't need acc. `return a.keySet().collect { a[it] * b[it] }.sum()`

Comment: I've never used Groovy but you could try either `a.collect { k, ak -> ak * b[k] }.sum()` or `a.inject(0) { acc, k, ak -> acc + ak + b[k] }`.

Comment: @AlinPandichi, do you want to post your comment as an answer? I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need acc.

```
return a.keySet().collect { a[it] * b[it] }.sum()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have a solution quite similar to what you are doing now leveraging [inject](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#inject(groovy.lang.Closure)) (Groovy's [functional fold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29)), so that:

```
def a = [1:1, 2:2, 3:3]
def b = [1:2, 2:4, 3:6]

assert (1*2 + 2*4 + 3*6) == a.inject(0) { result, k, v -> result += v * b[k] }
```

Anyway, *Alin Pandichi's* solution

```
assert 28 == a.keySet().collect({ a[it] * b[it] }).sum()
```

is likely clearer if you are not quite familiar with functional groovy. Beware that this one creates an array of numbers before summing all values.

If you are using Java 8 and Groovy > 2.3, you can leverage Java 8 Streams API and use a Groovy closure as Java lambda:

```
assert 28 == a.entrySet().stream().mapToInt({ it.value * b[it.key] }).sum()
```

where [`IntStream.sum()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#sum--) is used instead of [`Iterable.sum()`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Iterable.html#sum()).